# "a coroutine was expected, got None"

Tags: python, python-asyncio

**OBJECTIVE**

I am trying to use `asyncio` to download multiple images at once.

**PROBLEM**

I am receiving the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Ze\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.1\scratches\scratch_1.py",
> line 175, in 
> loop.run_until_complete(main())   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 647, in
> run_until_complete
> return future.result()   File "C:\Users\Ze\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.1\scratches\scratch_1.py",
> line 163, in main
> await get_image_links(all_links)   File "C:\Users\Ze\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.1\scratches\scratch_1.py",
> line 89, in get_image_links
> current_task = asyncio.create_task(await fetch_image(img, i))   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 361, in
> create_task
> task = loop.create_task(coro)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 438, in
> create_task
> task = tasks.Task(coro, loop=self, name=name) TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got None
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

**CODE**

I tried cleaning it up and removing irrelevant code, so I apologize if it looks weird.

```
async def get_image_links(all_links):
    for index, link in enumerate(all_links.split()):
        response = requests.get(link, cookies=cookies, headers=headers).content

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
        page_html = str(soup.find("div", {"class": "entry-content"}))

        all_images = list(set([re.sub(r'-[0-9]+x[0-9]+', '', x) for x in re.findall(r'((?:https?://)[^\",]+(?:jpe?g|webp|png))', page_html)]))

        entry_data = str(soup.find("footer", {"class": "entry-meta"}))

        agency = re.search('Category: .+?>([^<]+)', entry_data).group(1)
        name = re.search('Tags: .+?>([^<]+)', entry_data).group(1)
        folder_name = name + " - " + agency

        location = os.path.join(base_location, folder_name)

        if not os.path.exists(location):
            os.makedirs(location)

        async def fetch_image(img, img_index):
            image_name = img.split('/')[-1]
            save_path = os.path.join(location, image_name)

            # if the image has already been downloaded, skip it
            if os.path.exists(save_path):
                print("Skipping")
                return

            print("Fetching image " + str(img_index + 1) + " of " + str(len(all_images)) + " for link " + str(index + 1) + " of " + str(len(all_links.split())))
            save_image(save_path, requests.get(img).content)

        tasks = []

        for i, img in enumerate(all_images):
            current_task = asyncio.create_task(await fetch_image(img, i))

            tasks.append(current_task)

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def main():
    await get_image_links(all_links)

all_links = [#links]

# just to make sure there are not any problems caused by two event loops
if asyncio.get_event_loop().is_running():  # only patch if needed (i.e. running in Notebook, Spyder, etc)
    import nest_asyncio

    nest_asyncio.apply()

# for asynchronous functionality
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Comment: Can you paste the rest of the error output?

Comment: Post the full stack trace and the actual code. What you have here isn't valid python code.

Comment: You are passing an empty object to one of these functions, it's usefull to know which object is being passed to which function, so please post the entire error message

Comment: Sorry about that! I included everything now but I figured it out. I used "await" when creating the tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way You gather tasks. The coroutine function `fetch_image` does not return anything, so `await fetch_image(...)` results in nothing (`None`).

Replace those lines:

```
for i, img in enumerate(all_images):
    current_task = asyncio.create_task(await fetch_image(img, i))

    tasks.append(current_task)

await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

With following:

```
for i, img in enumerate(all_images):
    tasks.append(fetch_image(img, i))

await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```